# How to show/open JavaFX DatePicker editor to a specific calendar date without setting any value in its textbox?

Tags: javafx, javafx-datepicker

I wish to enable date picking for a time range `Jan 2000 - Dec 2014` and have disabled dates outside this range and want to open the DatePicker editor to a date within this range without setting value(setValue() or Constructor) to it, since I want the text box empty. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set date you need by constructor or setValue and clear textbox with `picker.getEditor().clear()`.
To disable dates from outside you can set custom DateCellFactory:

```
    LocalDate minDate = LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 1);
    LocalDate maxDate = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.DECEMBER, 31);
    DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(minDate.plusYears(2));
    picker.setDayCellFactory((p) -> new DateCell() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(LocalDate ld, boolean bln) {
            super.updateItem(ld, bln);
            setDisable(ld.isBefore(minDate) || ld.isAfter(maxDate));
        }
    });
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        picker.getEditor().clear();
    });
```

Comment: This answers my question. Then I just needed to add this `    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        picker.getEditor().clear();
    });` inside an addListener for showingProperty of the datePicker to make it work as I wanted, since I wanted the datePicker textfield cleared each time until user selects a valid date.